# How to use the implicit function theorem in this case?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Really hit a wall with this one:

Prove that the equations:
$$2x+y+2z+u-v-1=0\\xy+z-u+2v-1=0\\yz+xz+u^2-v=0$$

define around $(u,v,x,y,z)=(1,1,-1,1,1)$ a single function $\phi(u,v)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$. Find $D\phi(1,1)$

I believe I have to use the implicit function theorem, but I don't know how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

basically what you have to do is set the function:
$$
F(x,y,z,u,v)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
F_1\\
F_2\\
F_3
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2x+y+2z+u−v−1\\
xy+z−u+2v−1\\
yz+xz+u^2−v
\end{array}\right)
$$

Then you notice F(1,1,-1,1,1)=0. And you find the derivative with respect the variables you want to clear
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial (x,y,z)}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y} &\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial z}  \\
\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y} &\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z}  \\
\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x} &\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial y} &\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z} 
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 & 1 &2\\
y & x &1\\
z & z &y
\end{array}\right)
$$
And evaluated at the desired point
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial (x,y,z)}(1,1,-1,1,1)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 & 1 &2\\
1 & 1 &1\\
-1 & -1 &1
\end{array}\right)
$$
And check that it has maximum rank, for instance as this is a square matrix we can check the determinant is non-zero.
$$
det\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial (x,y,z)}(1,1,-1,1,1)\right)=2\neq 0
$$
So by the implicit function theorem., there exist $\phi$ as you want. To get the derivative:
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial(u,v)}(1,1)=-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial(x,y,z)}(1,1,-1,1,1)\right)^{-1}\frac{\partial F}{\partial(u,v)}(1,1,-1,1,1)\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial(u,v)}(1,1)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 & -2 &0\\
-3 & 4 &1\\
-1 & 0 &1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 & -1\\
-1 & 2\\
2 &-1
\end{array}\right)\\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial(u,v)}(1,1)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
4 & -6\\
-5 & 10\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: hmmmm I messed up on the derivative $\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial z}=x+y$instead of $y$. But it just changes the number, the procedure is the same

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand how to approach a group of equations. And the process is the part I was interested in the most, really thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f: \Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$,

$$f(u,v,x,y,z) =( 2x+y+2z+u-v-1, xy+z-u+2v-1, yz+xz+u^2-v)$$

We have:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial(x,y,z)} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 2 \\ y & x & 1 \\ z & z & x + y \end{pmatrix} $$

So:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial(x,y,z)}(1,1,-1,1,1) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

which has determinant $3 \neq 0$ (hence invertible).

Finally, $f(1,1,-1,1,1) = 0$. So, by the implicit function theorem, there are two open sets $U \subset \Bbb R^2$ and $V \subset \Bbb R^3$, such that $(1,1) \in U$ and $(-1,1,1) \in V$, and a differentiable map $\phi: U \to V$, such that $f(u,v, \phi(u,v)) = 0$ for all $(u,v) \in U$. $\phi$ is the desired map. Now, by the second part of the IFT, we have:

$$D \Phi(1,1) = \left[ \frac{\partial f}{\partial(x,y,z)} (1,1,-1,1,1) \right]^{-1} \frac{\partial f}{\partial(u,v)}(1,1,-1,1,1)$$

Now:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial(u,v)} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ 2u & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

At $(1,1,-1,1,1)$, this becomes:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Thus;

$$D\phi(1,1) = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \\ 2 & -1 \end{pmatrix} = \frac13 \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 4 \\ 8 & -7 \\ -1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I really needed this process, thank you. I see it is pretty similar to the only case I had seen (F(x,y,z)=0), but I couldn't totally grasp this one before. Should there be a "-" in front of the last multiplication?
Thank you!

Comment: @Eldyrd it is corrected now. You're welcome